# A question about Q?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, gn.general-topology

Let A=$\{a_n : n\in \omega \}\subset 2^{\omega\times\omega}$ be nonempty countable without isolated points (i.e. homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$), and satisfy $ \forall n\in \omega \exists^\infty m|\{k:a_n(m,k)=1\}|=\omega $.
Does there exist $ a\in cl(A)\setminus A$ satisfying $\exists^\infty m|\{k:a(m,k)=1\}|=\omega $?

Comment: what's the meaning of "$\exists^\infty$"?

Comment: "There are infinitely many"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is no, as shown by the following set $A$ (whose elements I will describe as subsets rather than binary functions).

For any map $\sigma:\omega\to\omega+1:=\omega\cup\{\omega\}$ define its hypograph
$$\mathrm{hypo}(\sigma):=\{(m,k)\in\omega\times\omega: k < \sigma(m)\}\subset\omega\times\omega\\ .$$

An increasing map $\sigma:\omega\to\omega+1$   takes the value $\omega$ if and only if its hypograph contains a subset of the form $[n,\omega)\times \omega$, thus, if and only if it has the property **(P)** stated in the question (there exist infinitely many $m$ such that there exist infinitely many $k$ such that $(m,k)\in \mathrm{hypo}(\sigma)$; which is indeed verified quite in a strong way).

Let $A$ be the set of all  hypographs of all  increasing maps that take  the value $\omega$. Clearly, the set $A$ is countable, with no isolated points; and all its elements enjoy  property **(P)**. A point in $\mathrm{cl}(A)\setminus A$ is exactly the hypograph of an increasing $\omega$-valued map, which never satisfies  property **(P)**.

Comment: Nice example Pietro.

Comment: Tanks for your answer,you are right.